# Create interface + Class wrapper from abstract references

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following objects with the following fields:

```
class ObjectA
{
    float progress;
    bool isDone;
}

class ObjectB
{
    bool canceled;
}
```

I want to create `ObjectC` which would be bound to, and have `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` fields `progress`, `isDone` and `canceled`.

How can I do such a thing?

Is this possible via `dynamic` types or some Interface + ClassWrapper combo?

`ObjectA` and `ObjectB` types, classes, signatures etc can not be changed. They are given as they are.

Comment: please post correctly your code snippet by indenting the lines

Comment: What do you mean by "bound to"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible via normal ways, because your fields are private and thus not accessible to any code outside of `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`.

The only way to do it - which I don't recommend at all, because it breaks incapsulation - would be using reflection to access these members.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in c# as multibase inheritance of classes. The nicest way of doing such thing is declaring interfaces for each behavior:

```
interface IA
{
    float Progress {get;}
    bool IsDone {get;}
}

interface IB
{
    bool IsCanceled{get;}
}
```

and maybe third to aggregate former two:

```
interface IC : IA , IB
{
}
```

and implement both in one class.

```
class C : IC
{
    public float Progress { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    public bool IsCanceled { get; set; }
}
```

Then you must remember to program against interfaces not classes:

```
class SomeClass
{
  //If only IA features are required
  void DoSTH(IA c){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via composition:

```
public class ObjectC
{
    public ObjectA ProgressInfo { get; set; }

    public ObjectB CanceledInfo { get; set; }
}
```

or via interfaces:

```
public interface IProgressable
{
    float Progress { get; }

    bool IsDone { get; }
}

public interface ICancelable
{
    bool Canceled { get; }
}
```

then you could have your new class implementing both interfaces:

```
public class ObjectC : IProgressable, ICancelable
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `multiple inheritance`, which is not supported by C#.

One solution is to use interfaces, but it requires you to implement the code multiple times:

```
public interface IFoo1
{
    float Progress { get; set; }
    bool IsDone { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo2
{
    bool Canceled { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ObjectA : IFoo1
{
    public float Progress { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ObjectB : IFoo2
{
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectC : IFoo1, IFoo2
{
    public float Progress { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I meant I can not change ObjectA and ObjerctB classes. and so can not add uinterfaces to them